# Confused: I have a tendency to begin sentences after semicolon by using verbs in the participle. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: semicolons, participles

From the marker of my essay:

The author has a tendency to begin sentences after semicolon by using verbs in the participle. bold is the problem.

I have made up some sentences which demonstrate this point:

"The dog which had mauled the women had black hair and a long tail. The dog that was caught was white and black with no tail; **strongly suggesting** that it was not this dog that had attacked the women.

“It is quite fitting that I should begin my analysis of tradition with John Doe, who was a genuine explorer of the Church in the 11th century. **Thereby demonstrating** that exploration was quite common during this period …”

So what am I doing wrong in reference to using a participle after a semicolon, and how do I fix it? [English second language]

Thank you for your help and support in this matter.

Comment: The semicolon separated two related but distinct independent clauses. Your clauses after the semicolon are not independent. That's all. Fix it by studying again the function of the semicolon; practice it by connecting closely related independent clauses with one.

Comment: I'd say this is purely a comment on the fact that you do not use interpunction according to the rules we are taught.

Comment: This isn't a question for Writers; it centers on how to appropriately use a semi-colon.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Surely that means it is an appropriate question for Writers, because punctuation usage has nothing to do with the English language ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii We have lots of punctuation questions here.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Exactly my point! Close them all! (I'm only half joking.)

Comment: @curious if you feel strongly about it, you could propose it on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that the essay marker is referring to involves positioning fragmentary clauses in such a way (due to the power of the semicolon to impose a strong break in the sentence in which it appears) that they seem to be trying to function as independent clauses. One way to avoid this problem is to change the punctuation mark in each case from a semicolon to a comma (as Brian Hitchcock suggests in his answer). This works fine in the first example:

> The dog which had mauled the women had black hair and a long tail. The dog that was caught was white and black with no tail, strongly suggesting that it was not this dog that had attacked the women.

but less well in the second example, which begins to feel run-on, especially as the word *thereby* seems more closely connected to the "I" in "I should" than to anything else in the example:

> It is quite fitting that I should begin my analysis of tradition with John Doe, who was a genuine explorer of the Church in the 11th century, thereby demonstrating that exploration was quite common during this period.

The other straightforward way to overcome the problem  is to replace the semicolon with a period and start a new sentence that explicitly identifies the subject that (in each case) your originally wording sidesteps. In the first example, you might do this:

> The dog which had mauled the women had black hair and a long tail, but the dog that was caught was white and black with no tail. The differences in their identifying characteristics strongly suggest that the captured dog was not the one that had attacked the women.

And in the second example you might try something like this:

> It is quite fitting that I should begin my analysis of tradition with John Doe, a genuine explorer of the Church in the 11th century. Doe's life conveniently illustrates the fact that exploration was quite common during this period.

At least in the early phases of gaining mastery over English as a writer, I think it is a good idea to be as clear as possible about the things you are describing. In part being clear involves taking pains to identify pronoun referents and subjects or objects that modifying phrases attach to. And in part it means not letting a series of modifiers carry you too far afield from the basic idea or series of ideas that you are trying to convey.

Comment: Thank you Sven Yargs for your explanation, it has been very helpful. I will go back to the basics and try to avoid these errors in my future essays.

Answer (score 0):

Use commas rather than semicolon or period in cases like those you cited.